# up-to-date white paper on converting T-SQL stored-procs and UDFs to Postgres PL/pgSQL

Tags: plpgsql, database-migration

I would be grateful for a link to a white paper on migrating T-SQL stored procedures and user-defined functions to the current flagship version of Postgres. Ideal would be one that would give us a good sense of the task ahead by highlighting any areas where the two databases accomplish a task or provide a solution to a requirement in a different manner and there isn't a direct counterpart (built-in system @@functions and granularity of triggers are two areas that come to mind, but I imagine there might well be others, like the Date Math or string handling libraries).

Comment: @Mr Lister: the question is phrased in terms of the "from" database  rather than the "to" database -- not a value-judgment :-)

Comment: @Mr Lister: I've edited the original question to avoid all implications of a lack of neutrality on my part.